# MS teams Messaging Extensions c# aspnetcore 3.1 not working when ssl is enable in my VS solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-teams, messaging

[image]I have implemented ms teams messaging extensions using c# aspnetcore 3.1 as described [in here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action)
i can trigger both search command and actions command and return card results when i disable  enable ssl options in sol -> properties -> debug -> enable ssl option
is there any way or m i missing any thing that is no working with ssl option checked

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you have missed providing the link. Please elaborate or provide some screenshot to clarify.

Comment: @Saonti-MSFT updated the implementation link 
messaging extension doesn't work when i have ssl setting enabled in my visual studio

Comment: Hi @ParthPatil, Could you please try disabling SSL and change the port in App Url and try the sample.

Comment: Moving to answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Please try disabling SSL and change the port in App Url and try the sample.

Comment: as described in post above i can trigger it when ssl is  disabled. Although i have resolve my issue for ngrok by signing up at https://ngrok.com/ this allowed me to use https url
thanks for the help and sorry for late reply